# How do I center two divs within a larger div?

Tags: css

I am trying to center two divs (`#about` and `#testimonial-snippets`) within the larger black div. How can I do this?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DgtqM/

HTML

```
<footer>
        <div id="footer-section">
            <section id="about">
                <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img class="profile-photo" src="http://dummyimage.com/42x42/000/fff" alt="profile" height="44" width="44"></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Find him on <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">Twitter</a> and <a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank">Instagram</a>. <a id="slide-toggle" href="#">Contact</a> | <a href="">Archive</a></p>
            </section>
            <section id="testimonial-snippets">
                <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img class="profile-photo" src="http://dummyimage.com/42x42/000/fff" alt="profile" height="44" width="44"></a>
                <div class="snippet">
                    <p>This is a testimonial.</p>
                    <a class="read-testimonial" href="/testimonials">read more</a>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
background: #222;
clear: both;
color: #f4f3f1;
float: left;
padding: 50px 0;
width: 100%;
}
#footer-section {
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 940px;
}
footer section {
float: left;
width: 300px;
}
#about {
margin-right: 20px;
}
footer a {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #f4f3f1;
color: #f4f3f1;
}
.profile-photo {
border: 1px solid #f4f3f1;
float: left;
margin: 4px 10px 10px 0;
}
p {
margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: will your outer and inner div have fixed width?

Comment: @Kasyx `footer` is 100% and `#footer-section` is 940px. The two divs inside `#footer-section` is 300px each.

Comment: @Desi Don't forget the `20px margin` on the about section.  That adds to the width (300 x 2) + 20 = 620px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the elements within a new div.  Then give the new div a fixed width and use `margin: 0px auto` for styling.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer-section">
   <div class="wrap">
    <section id="about">
      <!--Content -->
    </section>
    <section id="testimonial-snippets">
      <!--Content-->
    </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    width: 620px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/DgtqM/5/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but forgot to set a width. Thanks!

Comment: @Desi No problem, Hoped it helped!

Answer (score 3):

I allowed myself to reduce that problem to a minimum of markup. Everything else is not relevant to the question and only makes it harder to understand.

```
<footer>
    <section id="about">About</section>
    <section id="testimonial-snippets">Testimonial</section>
</footer>
```

One solution would be to make these sections `inline-block` elements and have them centered in the footer:

```css
footer {
    background: #222;
    padding: 50px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
footer section {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
/* Just coloring the different divs */
#about { background: red; }
#testimonial-snippets { background: green; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DgtqM/6/